# Does the game keep the last vehicle you drove when you start a mission?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I was playing as Michael and found an abandoned police car. I began driving it to Lester when I got a call from Amanda saying to come pick her up in a police car after she was arrested. I got out of my police car and got into her police car and then drove away trying to lose the cops. Upon returning her home, I saw a police car in my driveway. Does the game just store whatever vehicle you last drove before starting a mission in your driveway?

Comment: I think the is the case, since it has happened to me as well. Confirmation would be nice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTA 5 will always save your last vehicle... even if you are online and go into certain game types or missions... think of it this way:

1. You take a car
2. You may or may not take it to Los Santos Customs and say spend $0-$10,000+ of your money... but without putting on moors mutual insurance... the game won't delete the car object as it has certain triggers to prevent the loss of your latest vehicles.

Other factors that will interact with this feature will be:

1. Getting a new car off the street. (Excluding vehicles that are 100% requirements during a side mission)
2. Turning off your games console / PC
3. Using one of your vehicles from the garage
4. Not driving the car and leaving it for a prolonged period of time (~1hr+ ...note the game also has a viewport feature... so this means if you look at the car it will stay there no doubt, but if the car is not visible and it's far away... the timer will kick in).
5. Leaving the radius of the games object instance field. (So driving too far away from the vehicle).

For precise values on these triggers you will need to ask a developer or de-compile the GTA 5 code. (providing it's in a readable manner (most likely not... it would most likely be 'smallified', aka garbage looking code that uses less data to perform the same actions.), but there's another chance that it would be readable as they are open to future updates and maintenance of the game files)... so your best bet is to wait for the next GTA games hack tool that can read/convert the ff files. (I think the last one was IV Needle, but I may be getting mixed up).

Disclaimer: By reading and understanding this information you will not hold me in any form accountable for losses.